# Cloud Run 502 Bad Gateway - Protocol Error

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-run, http-status-code-502

Currently working on a microservice architecture where I have one particular microservice that will have a specific mechanism :

1. Receiving a Request saying it needs some data

   - Sending Status 202 - Accepted To Client
   - Generating Data and Saving it to a redis instance
2. Receiving a Request to see if data is ready

   - Data is not ready in redis instance : Sending status 102 To Client
   - Data is ready in redis instance : sending it back

The first point works fine with this kind of code :

```
res.sendStatus(202)
processData(req)
```

But I have different behavior Locally and when hosted on Cloud Run for the second point.

Locally, the 2nd request is not handled while the first one process is not ended and I presumed it was normal on a threading perspective.

Is there something that might be used to make express still handle the other request while the first one is sent to the client but the process is not ended ?

But considering that Google Cloud Run is based on instances and auto-scaling, I thought that well, the first one is locked because the process is not ended ? No problem ! A new one will come and handle the other request that will then check the redis instance key status.

It seems that I was wrong ! When I do the call to check the status of the data, if the data is not yet done, Cloud run send me back this error (502 Gateway) :

> upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: protocol error

However, I don't have any res status to 502 so it seems that either Cloud Run or Express send this itself.

My only option would be to split my Cloud Run instance into a Cloud Function + a Cloud Run. The Cloud run would trigger the process in a Cloud Function but I'm pretty short on time so if I don't have any other option I will have to do that but I would hope to be able to manage it without introducing a new Cloud Function

Do you have any explanation about the fact that id doesn't worky locally and on Cloud run ?

My considerations are not convincing me and I don't find any truth :

- Maybe a client can't do 2 request at the same time : Which seems not logical
- Maybe express can't handle several request at the same time : Which does not seems logical to me

Any clues that seems more plausible ?

Comment: Why are you using 102/202 status codes? Just process the request and return 200 or an error. Do not process requests after the HTTP response has been sent. Complete the request and then send the response.

Comment: I would have prefered that. But given the processing time and the risk of network loss in this particular context we have no other choice than having a first call to process the data that may be huge, store it for 30 minutes into a redis cache and retrieve it to the client throught multiple paginated call to make sure the size stay decent.

Comment: I do not think Cloud Run supports your programming model. Cloud Run is an HTTP Request/Response system. The GFE proxies requests. Once you return a response the lifetime of your service ends. However, without code, I am not certain of what you are actually implementing.

Comment: That's where things start to be out of my logic. The process, even if it takes 3 or 5 minutes go perfectly well and do whatever I need. But during the process time I can't do anything and only get a 502 error. I'll add some more details in the question later.

Comment: @Gregory Can you please provide the code/more details in the question as mentioned in the above comment? So we can help you in a better way.